# Vaadin 8 Grid no longer had grid.addRow(obj)

Tags: spring, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I was recently handed a Vaadin 7 project where the previous developer used Vaadin 7 Grid grid.addRow(obj) to add rows to the grid. Now in Vaadin 8 Grid the have added grid.setItems(? Collection ?) which totally wipes out the data in the Grid on grid.setItems(). I watched all the YouTube videos from Vaadin and all the stack overflow pages and found no answer.

I did find this forum with a bunch of people having the same problem: 
https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/15724440

Here is my work around and I'm not proud of it. Basically adding an ArrayList as my example uses a Person class with firstName, lastName, email, and salary.

```
@SpringUI(path = "/person")
@Theme("valo")
public class PersonForm extends UI{

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;
    List<Person> entries = new ArrayList<Person>();
    private TextField firstName = new TextField("First Name");
    private TextField lastName = new TextField("Last Name");
    private TextField email  = new TextField("Email Address");
    private TextField salary  = new TextField("Salary");
    private Person person = new Person();
    private Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>(Person.class);
    final private FormLayout layout = new FormLayout();

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request){

        grid.getEditor().isEnabled();
        grid.setColumnOrder("firstName", "lastName",
                "email", "salary");

        layout.addComponent(firstName);
        layout.addComponent(lastName);
        layout.addComponent(email);
        Button save = new Button("Save", e-> {

            addPersonToGrid(new Person(firstName.getValue(), lastName.getValue(), email.getValue(),salary.getValue()));

            Notification.show("PERSON WAS SAVED");
        });

        layout.addComponent(save);
        layout.addComponent(grid);
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

    }

    public void addPersonToGrid(Person person){
        entries.add(person);
        grid.setItems(entries);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in that there is no addRow / addBean method anymore in Vaadin8.
However you could work with a DataProvider which is very neat instead of using the old BeanItemContainer. You can set Filters and SortOrders directly on the DataProvider now.

It would be easier to use a DataProvider like this:

```
private ListDataProvider<Person> provider = ListDataProvider.ofCollection(entries);

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request){
  grid.setDataProvider(provider);
  ........
}

public void addPersonToGrid(Person person){
    entries.add(person);
    provider.refreshAll();
}

public void editPersonToGrid(int idx, Person person){
    entries.set(idx, person);
    provider.refreshItem(person);
}
```

It is not as neat as just calling entries.add(person) and everything else being handled automatically, but it works with large dataSets and is very convenient if you use filters and sorting.

Comment: Works Thank you!